# How to fire the attributeChanged-Function in Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have a simple Polymer canvas object like this:

```
<polymer-element name="canvas-diagram" attributes="type width height json">
  <template>
    <div id="canvasField">
        Typ: {{type}}, Width:<input value="{{width}}">, Height:{{height}}, json:{{json}}
        <div id="canvasContainer">
            <canvas id="canvasObj" width="{{width}}" height="{{height}}"></canvas>
        </div>    
    </div>
  </template>
  <script>
      function getMaxOfArray(numArray) {
        return Math.max.apply(null, numArray);
    }
    Polymer("canvas-diagram",{
        type: "bar",
        width: "300",
        height: "200",
        ready: function() {
             console.log("this.ready()");
            this.writeDiagram();
        },
        attributeChanged: function(attrName, oldVal, newVal) {
            console.log("this.attributeChanged()");
            console.log(attrName, 'old: ' + oldVal, 'new:', newVal);
            this.writeDiagram();
        },
        writeDiagram : function(){
           [...]
        },

      json: {
        data:[
            {"name":"Texts","value":"150"},
            {"name":"Videos","value":"50"},
            {"name":"Audio","value":"30"},
            {"name":"Test","value":"20"},
            {"name":"Test","value":"20"},
            {"name":"Test","value":"20"}
        ]}
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

But when I canhage an attribute manually the attributeChanged() Function doesnt fire. What am I doing wrong? I I habe that binded input threre. Changing it wont fire the Function ald also when I change the Attricute from the canvas-diagram-Element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends on the attribute changing. i don't think there is a global way to check all attributed for change. i am  pretty sure you have to check each attribute by it's self for change. for example if i wanted to know when the type attribute of your element change i would use a function like.

```
typeChanged: function () {
  console.log(this.type);
}
```

you would then need to make a function like the one above for each attribute you need a function to fire when changed.

edit: below is a easiest example i could think of. the button will change the text attribute of the element and the change will fire the textChanged function which will trigger the alert.

http://plnkr.co/edit/7swMG6dwMqwyutwMaYfd?p=preview

Comment: This doesnt work too. I have the

<canvas-diagram height="900" width="500" type="bar"></canvas-diagram>

Tag and a fuctions hould fire when I change some of these Attributes.

Comment: what attribute are you wanting to check for change?

Comment: Every single one of them. For example the width attribute. And then I want to rerender everything.

Comment: i use this method all the time to check changes to published attributes. looking over you element most of the stuff you are looking for change do not appear to use the this. prefix. and i am pretty sure that is required. working on a plunker so you can see it work.

Comment: You misuderstood my intention. I Want to change the Attribute in the HTML Element and want a function fired. Like in your plunker example:

<test-element text="test"></test-element>

document.getElementsByTagName("test-element")[0].text="anderer Text";

When everything inside the element should change but as far as I can see the given Attributes are always checked once.

Comment: maybe i did misunderstand your question but this is how the attributeChanged option works. i can change the text from anywhere i just did it on the element for simplicity. i can use document.querySelector('test-element').text = "newText"; and it will fire the function the same way. i updated the plunker to show changing the text inside and outside the element.

Comment: You are right. Thank you. But I now have a next Problem with my canvas rednering. Next Question....